# Plotly displaying console output

Tags: r, plotly

I cannot get plot_ly to not display console output in Isoslides

this is my code

```
plot_ly(data = mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, z = ~hp, 
        type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers") %>%
  add_markers(color = ~cyl, colors = "Viridis",
              symbol = ~gear, size = I(5)) %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "mpg"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "disp"),
                      zaxis = list(title = "hp")),
         margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't because of the code you've got here, this is from the call for the library. You can suppress the library messages, though. Instead of `library(plotly)` use `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plotly))`